# YouTube API - onPlayerStateChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm using the YouTube API in conjunction with Cyclone Slider. The goal is to pause the slideshow once the YouTube starts playing. I'm using the following code which works nicely:

```html
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
</script>

<script>
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video', {
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 1) {
        $(".cycle-slideshow").cycle('pause');
    }

    if(event.data === 2) {
        $(".cycle-slideshow").cycle('resume');
    }
}
</script>
```

However, it only seems to work if I do a refresh of the page. If I navigate between pages and return to the homepage, it will no longer work.

Any suggestions for why this is the case? I've tried a few suggestions I found on Google but couldn't get any to work. I'm a little lost on this one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using something like jquery mobile?  Or is your page navigation AJAX dependent?

Comment: Nope, none of that, just your standard WordPress website. It's just a little strange as the code above works great the first time, but once I move around the site and return to the homepage, it won't fire again.

Comment: What does your console say during your navigation back to the youtube page?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, it works for me -

```
function loadYouTube(targetId){
    ytplayer = new YT.Player(targetId, {
        events: {
            'onStateChange': function(event){
                /** YouTube API
                        -1 (unstarted)
                        0 (ended)
                        1 (playing)
                        2 (paused)
                        3 (buffering)
                        5 (video cued)
                 **/
                if (event.data == 1) {
//do your work here
                }
                console.log(event.data)
            }
        }    
    });
}
```

Comment: Using this has the same problem as my code, it works on a page refresh, but if I navigate around the website and land back on the homepage, it won't fire unfortunately.

Comment: It might be because of the API events are still not binded to the youtube video and when you refresh the page the events are binded. I faced the same problem. I use AJAX to post content on page which includes the youtube videos but the events are not automatically binded to the videos as I was doing it inside the post loop. **If you have similar problem**, try invoking the method with the target id after you post it.

Comment: I'm getting same issue. Error is 

Error: The YouTube player is not attached to the DOM.
    at W.g.C (https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflPSGdpW/www-widgetapi.js:121:224)
    at V (https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflPSGdpW/www-widgetapi.js:113:99)
    at W.(anonymous function).getCurrentTime.Kb.(anonymous function) [as pauseVideo] (https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflPSGdpW/www-widgetapi.js:131:124)