# How to auto play the next video when the current video is ended with Youtube API v3?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api

At first I thought it was `autoplay=1` but this is to autoplay the video when you loaded the website. I'm using Javascript to do everything (show video, next button, connect the API, etc).

Comment: might be a duplicate question. does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725950/youtube-related-videos-using-youtube-v3-api

Comment: I totally forgot about this post, but I found the solution for my problem: onPlayerStateChange https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553570/youtube-api-onplayerstatechange